# after select array how i append select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, append

if I select three products after selecting when I click on edit.
after editing selected items are showing but when I select in edit add more product, the add more product selection opens between 1 and 2 products......

```
  var i = 0;
    $('#add').click(function(){
        ++i;
        $('#selectproduct').append(`<div class="row" id="newProduct${i}">
             <div class="col-5">
                <div class="mb-1">
                    <label class="form-label">Select Product</label>
                     <select class="form-select" name="product[]" onchange="PushOptionValuesToREnt(this.value,${i})">
                                                                    <option selected disabled>--Select Product--</option>
                                                                    @foreach ($product as $key=>$val)
                                                                    <option value="{{ $val->name }}">{{ $val->name }}</option>
                                                                    @endforeach
                                                                </select>
                                                                @if($errors->has('product'))
                                                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first ('product')}}</span>
                                                                @endif
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col">
                                                            <div class="mb-1">
                                                                <label class="form-label">Frequently</label>
                                                                    <select class="form-select" onchange="frequentlyOption(this.value,${i})" id="frequently_${i}"   name="frequently_${i}">
                                                                    <option selected disabled>--Frequently--</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                    @if($errors->has('frequently_'))
                                                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first ('frequently_')}}</span>
                                                                    @endif
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col">
                                                            <div class="mb-1">
                                                                <label class="form-label">Rent</label>
                                                                <input type="number" name="rentper[]" id="rent_per_day_${i}" onChange="calculateAmount(${i})" class="form-control rent-per-day" value="{{ $addbillings->rentper }}" readonly>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col">
                                                            <div class="mb-1">
                                                                <label class="form-label">Qauntity/Days</label>
                                                                <input type="number" id="total_days_${i}" onChange="calculateAmount(${i})" name="quantity[]" class="form-control total-days" value="{{ $addbillings->quantity }}" >
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col">
                                                            <div class="mb-1">
                                                                <label class="form-label">Amount</label>
                                                                <input type="number" name="amount[]" class="form-control TotalAmount" id="per_day_amount_${i}" value="{{ $addbillings->amount }}" readonly>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="mb-1">
                                                            <button type="reset" name ="remove" onclick="removeRow(${i})" id="remove" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
                                                        </div>` );
                                                });
```

I want that if I select to add more products, the product will show after three.